# Power BI +1 and -1 day button

Tags: powerbi

I need to create a report that has a date picker that affects the whole report. The date picker is a slicer that opens up a calendar and then once a date is selected, they will get the data for the whole report. I have been asked to create arrow buttons that allow the user to scroll through dates... For example the "->" arrow would change the date to tomorrow and vice versa. I don't see a button for this scenario and am worried about using bookmarks because of they dynamic nature of the tool. I am trying to use a slicer and making it look like a button, but can I make a slicer for this scenario? Apologies if this is all over the place, I have been looking everywhere for an answer, but have been unsuccessful in finding anything close that has actually been answered.

I tried creating extra data tables to correlate with the custom slicer, but cannot slice on a measure like "[Calendar]'Single Day' - 1".

Comment: I don't think there's a native way to do this currently. Maybe a custom visual like "Play Axis (Dynamic Slicer)".